# Elasticsearch query: syntax for range restriction gives 400

Tags: python, rest, elasticsearch

I'm using python to communicate with an ElasticSearch server. I'm using the elasticsearch package, and I'm formatting queries and feeding them to the search function in the body parameter.

Sending queries worked just fine. For example, this query works:

```
{'query': {'constant_score': {'filter': {'bool': {'must': {'terms': {'id.keyword': ['d42bdc8a-a38b-43fa-9283-13b5e5c08c6e']}}}}}}}
```

I now want to restrict the range, so I add a little segment (indentation for clarity):

```
{'query': 
    {'constant_score': 
        {'filter': 
            {'bool': 
                {'must': 
                    {'range': 
                        {'startTime': 
                            {'format': "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS",
                             'gte': '2018-01-20T17:19:43.393',
                             'lte': '2018-04-01T17:19:43.393'}
                        },
                     'terms':
                         {'id.keyword':
                             ['d42bdc8a-a38b-43fa-9283-13b5e5c08c6e']
                         }
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
     }
}
```

A query that looks identical (to me) worked in R. I'm getting a status 400 though (bad request). Does anyone see what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there, this is the right query that will work:

```
{'query': 
    {'constant_score': 
        {'filter': 
            {'bool': 
                {'must': [
                    {'range': 
                        {'startTime': 
                            {'format': "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS",
                             'gte': '2018-01-20T17:19:43.393',
                             'lte': '2018-04-01T17:19:43.393'}
                        }
                    },
                    {
                     'terms':
                         {'id.keyword':
                             ['d42bdc8a-a38b-43fa-9283-13b5e5c08c6e']
                         }
                    }
                 ]
               }
             }
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was fast! Took me a second to see where I was going wrong. Guess I'm too much in a dict mindset or something :)